# Tosfos vs Tosfos HaRosh

Tags: talmud-gemara, rishonim, tosfot

I have noticed that the Tosfos HaRosh very often parallels the Tosfos on the page. Sometimes he presents almost identical information in a slightly different way, but very often he seems to be saying the same thing.

What is the relationship between the Tosfos on the page and the Tosfos HaRosh? Was the Rosh a Tosafist? Did he see the Tosfos that we have on the page?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tosafot

Comment: R. Dr. Jose Faur wrote an article on the nature of Tosafot HaRosh, particularly on Berakhot.

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/8435 ???

Answer (score 4):

[Menahem ben Aaron ibn Zerah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menahem_ben_Aaron_ibn_Zerah) writes in the [introduction to Tzeidah La-Derech](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14130&st=&pgnum=5) that the Rosh essentially built off of the Tosafos of Rabbeinu Shimshon of Shanz.

> גם חבר פרישה וקצור תוספו' רבינו שמשון משנ"ץ שהיה תלמיד מובהק מרבינו
>   יצחק בעל התוספות והוסיף בהן דקדוקין ופירושין משאר המחדשין ומהר"מ
>   מרוטנ"בורק שהיה רבו מובהק

[R. Joseph David Sinzheim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_David_Sinzheim) notes this towards the end of Sheva Chakiros and states that the Rosh did not really add anything of his own, so the Tosafos Ha-Rosh is a determining factor in interpreting Tosafos.

> דידוע הוא כי כל פי' בדברי התוס' ע"ד תוס' הרא"ש בודאי לא כיוונו אלי'
>   התוס' כי לפני הרא"ש הי' התוס' של רבינו שמשון שחי אחריו לדעתי לערך
>   שבעים שנה וכיון שהרא"ש כתב כן בוודאי היה כתוב כן בפירוש בתוס' שהרי מעט מן המעט שחידש הרא"ש מדעתו וא"כ הוא כתב כן בפי' ובכל חיבורי לא נטיתי מדורי' בפי' דברי התוס' ומה ששאל ר"מ מה הוא תוס' הרא"ש הנה הרא"ש למד עם תלמידי' הש"ס וכדי לקצר עשה קיצור מהתוס' ללמדם עם תלמידי' וכן מבואר בתשובה אחת בתשובת הרא"ש בענין עגונה כלל נ"א ס"ב והובא בטור אהע"ז סי' קי"ח וכן כתב בהקדמת צדה לדרך שחיבר ר' מנחם בן הקדוש ר' אהרן בן זרח תלמידו של ר' יהודא בן הרא"ש ואין בידינו היום סדפוס מתוס' הרא"ש רק על ארבע מסכתות יבמות כתובות מגילה שבועות והשאר עדיין בכ"י במדינת איטלי' וטורקיה ומחבריהם מביאים הרבה דברים בשאר מסכתות