# Looking for a sefer explaining the tosfos of maseches kesubos

Tags: product-recommendation, commentaries, tosfot, maseches-kesubos

Is anyone familiar with a sefer that explains the tosfos of maseches kesubos? (Aside from the first two chapters).

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65573 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40323 and maybe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66214

Comment: How in depth do you want? For poshut pshat, you can use the mesivta (like oz vehadar's version of artscroll but with explanations of rashi and tosfos too).

Comment: Artscroll’s ‘[Tosafos - Tractate Makkos](https://www.artscroll.com/Details.aspx?itemNo=9781422622292?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIs8L3lru35AIVDl8NCh1JfAf3EAQYASABEgLZU_D_BwE)’.

Answer (score 4):

Kollel Iyun HaDaf goes through all the Tosfos point by point,its really a great resource for learning,and best part its free.

http://dafyomi.co.il/section.php?gid=15&sid=13

Answer (score 1):

מי מנוחות 
On regular masechtos of Nashim and Nezikin

[Here](https://books.google.com/books/about/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA.html?id=cglwSQAACAAJ) on Google books

[מתיבתא](http://www.oz-vehadar.com/en/department/16/editions-of-the-metivta)  From Oz V'Hadar

Tosfos Hamevuar from Hamaor
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get תוספות המבאור on the whole of תלמוד בבלי- see [here](http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/31530693/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A8-%D7%99%D7%90-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D---%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8-)

Answer (score 0):

שערי תוספותShaare Tosfot:  [here](https://www.hamadaf-y.co.il/%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A1/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA/)

Comment: Thanks, but that is in the first chapter, I am looking for a Sefer for chapter 3 and further.